# How to test Observable with subscribe function in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

I have the following function in component.

```
@Output() data: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

testData() {
    observableRef.subscribe(() => {
      this.data.emit();
    }, () => {
      this.data.emit();
    });
  }
```

I would like to write the unit test cases for the above function, I have tried like the below:

```
it('should call testData method', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(observableRef, 'emit’);
    component.testData(component.data);
    expect(component.data.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    tick();
    discardPeriodicTasks();
}));
```

But, after running this test case, the code coverage is not going inside of subscribe function. I am not sure why, actually I am new to this unit testing, can anyone please help me on this to go inside subscribe and make it test case looks good.

Comment: You should be able to subscribe to `data` and see if anything is emitted.

Comment: @AndreiTătar Can you please elaborate more, what can i do here, with data subscribe also I am getting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to spy the `observableRef` and `component.data` emits and then call the `fixture.detectChanges()`:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

it("should call testData method", async(() => {

  spyOn(observableRef, 'emit').and.returnValue(of("some value"))
  spyOn(component.data, 'emit').and.returnValue(of("some value"))
  component.testData();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(component.data.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```